# Why does this tkinter event function not see the non-event variable?

Tags: python, function, events, tkinter, parameters

I have a button that is bound to an event function and I want that function to count the number of times the button has been clicked. So I have a variable (clicks), and i want the event function to take clicks as a parameter and increment it by one. Here is my code:

```
#imports
import tkinter

#variables
clicks = 0

#event functions
def click(event,clicks):
    clicks += 1
    print(clicks)
    return clicks

#create gui
window = tkinter.Tk()

button = tkinter.Button(text = "click me!")
button.pack()
clicks = button.bind("<Button-1>",click)

#run gui
window.mainloop()
```

When I run the program and click the button, I get a "click() missing 1 required positional argument: 'clicks'" error. But as far as I can tell I have clicks initialized, and click takes and returns clicks, so where have I gone wrong?

Comment: `bind()`  returns `bind_ID`, not value from function `click()` - and it send `"<Button-1>",click` on list and when you click mouse button then `mainloop` check it with list and when it find `"<Button-1>",click` then it execute `click(event)`, not `click(event, clicks)` so defining `def click(event,clicks):` is wrong. And using `return clicks` and `clicks = bind()` is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of things wrong with your code. but to answer your question, it's because you didn't declare the integer `clicks` variable `global` in event handler function. However that alone wouldn't make everything work, so I'm going to concentrate on the other issues present (as well as fix that one).

For one, you have *two* objects named `clicks`. As I already said, in order to change the value of the integer `clicks` object, it must be declared `global` in the `click()` event handler function — while it *is* possible to pass extra arguments to event handler functions, that wouldn't help here because integers are passed by value in Python, so incrementing it there wouldn't change the value of the global variable (so I'm not going to show you how to pass extra arguments since it wouldn't be helpful).

Lastly, and the most minor, there's no point in returning a value from an event handler function because `tkinter` simply ignores what they return (and *it* is what calls them).

Here's your code with modifications to make it work:

```
#imports
import tkinter

#variables
clicks = 0

#event handler function
def click(event):
    global clicks
    clicks += 1
    print(clicks)

#create gui
window = tkinter.Tk()

button = tkinter.Button(text="click me!")
button.pack()
button.bind("<Button-1>", click)

#run gui
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: From what I've read elsewhere, I thought it was bad form to use global, and that the 'better' method was to pass the variable into the function as a parameter. Does this method not work because tkinter will ignore the return?

Comment: @sam: That's generally true, but in the case of an immutable type, like an integer, you would either need to use a "trick" to get around that restriction or not make `clicks` a global variable (which is what it is regardless of whether you declare it as one in the function). Another way to avoid global variables is to start defining and using classes.

Comment: @sam in this situation `global` probably is the only solution. Using class you could run it with `self.clicks` instead of `global`. As for `return`. Function is not executed when you bind but much later and it is executed by `mainloop` and it doesn't know what to do with returned value - so using `return` is useless.